# Rewriting $a+b + |a- b|$

Tags: real-analysis

> Quoting: Write the following expression in equivalent forms not involving absolute values: $$a+b + |a- b|$$

long time I did not look at this. Here are all the cases I see existing:

Case 1: when $a \geq 0$, $b\geq0$, and $a> b$

Case 2: when $a \geq 0$, $b\geq0$, and $b> a$

Case 3: when $a \geq 0$, $b\leq0$

Case 4: when $a \leq 0$, $b\geq0$

Case 5: when $a \leq 0$, $b\leq0$, and $a> b$

Case 6: when $a \leq 0$, $b\leq0$, and $b> a$

am i going in the right direction? or is there another way more efficient?

any input is much appreciated

Comment: You only need two cases: $a \ge b$ or $b \ge a$. They overlap, but it won't affect the final answer.

Comment: Note that $$|a-b| = \begin{cases} a-b, & \text{if }a\ge b \\ -(a-b), & \text{if }a < b\end{cases}$$

Comment: You could also go with $a + b + |a-b| = 2\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: How about $a+b+\sqrt {(a-b)^2}\;$?

Answer (score 4):

The form of the formula varies depending on the sign of the expression $(a-b)$ under the module, therefore:

$$a+b + |a - b| = 
\begin{cases}
2b,\text{ if } a < b\\
2a,\text{ if } a\ge b.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Relatively to the answer of Darth Greek, $|x|=\max(x,-x)$.

Also $a+\max(b,c)=\max(a+b,a+c)$.

So $a+b+|a-b|=\max(a+b+a-b,a+b-(a-b))=\max(2a,2b)=2\max(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write:

$$|a-b|=\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$$

so:

$$a+b+\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$$