# prove $\text{abs}(a + b) + \text{abs}(a - b) = \text{max}(a, b) \cdot 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

after playing around with absolute value for a little, i noticed that $|a + b| + |a - b|$ always appeared to be the larger of $a$ and $b$ multiplied by $2$, whenever both $a$ and $b$ were positive.

$$
|a + b| + |a - b| =
\begin{cases}
2a, & \text{if $a \ge b$} \\
2b, & \text{if $a < b$}
\end{cases}
$$

can this be proven to always be the case, and if so, how do i prove it?

Comment: This is not true if you allow $a,b$ to be negative

Comment: oh right i forgot about that, sorry. though if a and b had to be positive, would this always be the case?

Comment: Do you mean the larger of $|a|$ or $|b|$ rather than $a$ and $b$? (I think it is true then. You could prove it by just splitting into cases based on the sign of the terms $a$, $b$, $a+b$, and $a-b$, though that'd be a bit painful)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1210728/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2950149/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2285899/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $a\ge b$  then $|a-b|=a-b$ and $\max\{a,b\}=a$, and
  $$ a+b+|a-b|=a+b+a-b=2a=2\max\{a,b\}.$$
- If $a\le b$  then $|a-b|=-(a-b)=b-a$  and $\max\{a,b\}=b$, and
  $$ a+b+|a-b|=a+b+b-a=2b=2\max\{a,b\}.$$

As this covers all cases for real $a,b$, we have
$$ a+b+|a-b|=2\max\{a,b\}$$
for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted to provide industrial strength approach for new students.

---

To prove:

> $|a + b| + |a - b| = 2\max(a,b).$

Either $a \geq b,$ or $a < b.$ 
Further, either $(a+b) \geq 0$ or $(a+b) < 0.$

**Case 1:** 
$a \geq b$ and $(a+b) \geq 0.$ 
Then $|a + b| + |a - b| = (a+b) + (a-b) = 2a = 2\max(a,b).$ 
The assertion is **always true** in this case.

**Case 2:** 
$a \geq b$ and $(a+b) < 0.$ 
Then $|a + b| + |a - b| = -(a + b) + (a - b) = -2b.$ 
$2a = 2\max(a,b).$ 
The assertion is **not always true** in this case.

**Case 3:** 
$a < b$ and $(a+b) \geq 0.$ 
Then $|a + b| + |a - b| = (a+b) + (b-a) = 2b = 2\max(a,b).$ 
The assertion is **always true** in this case.

**Case 4:** 
$a < b$ and $(a+b) < 0.$ 
Then $|a + b| + |a - b| = -(a+b) + (b - a) = -2a.$ 
$2b = 2\max(a,b).$ 
The assertion is **not always true** in this case.